# Waiting for animations to complete before hiding objects

Tags: ios, animation, uiview

I want an object to fade away and then hide it. The following hides it but I do not see the fading, presumably because it hides it while the animation is still being completed. Any advice how to make the code to wait until the animation has completed?

```
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];

    [adviceBorder setAlpha:0];

    [UIView commitAnimations];

    adviceBorder.hidden=YES;
```

Comment: Use the  `animateWithDuration:animations:completion:` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use block based animations and do the hiding in completion block

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                 animations:^{
                     adviceBorder.alpha = 0;
                 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     adviceBorder.hidden = YES;
                 }];
```

Comment: Just to add to this; there is no reason to set it to hidden after alpha has been set to below 0.02. It is not getting rendered, nor is it getting any touch inputs. Doing it this way means that you have to remember to turn the alpha back to 1 after setting hidden back to NO, increases the potential for bugs in your UI.

Answer (score 0):

you can use block for this .

After committing animation you can put code given below

```
  double delayInSeconds = 0.5;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    //code to be executed on the main queue after delay
   adviceBorder.hidden=YES;
});
```

Comment: Avoid dispatch_after .. I guess in this case it is fine but you create not-defined/randomized apps with race conditions